# Python: export to DXF file the Shapely objects

Tags: python, shapefile, dxf, wkt, shapely

How to export the results come from spatial operations such as `buffer` function on points using `Shapely` package for **Python** to a **DXF** file? BTW, googling wasn't so helpful this time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [SDXF](http://www.kellbot.com/sdxf-python-library-for-dxf/) library ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder how to convert Shapely objects to SDXF objects. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

One way is thanks to the `__geo_interface__` interface standard and the [ezdxf](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

A sample code could be below were `shapes` holds your e.g. MultiPolygon

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import ezdxf
import ezdxf.addons.geo

doc = ezdxf.new()
geoproxy = ezdxf.addons.geo.GeoProxy.parse(mapping(shapes))

msp = doc.modelspace()

# Use LWPOLYLINE instead of hatch.
for entity in geoproxy.to_dxf_entities(polygon=2): 
    msp.add_entity(entity)

doc.saveas("test.dxf")
```